# The $document_root variable cannot be used in the "root" directive

Tags: nginx

While setting up my nginx configuration I came upon this. Does anyone have any idea on why this happens exactly?

```
root /folder/my_root;

 index index.php index.html index.htm;
 error_page 404 /404.html;
 location = /404.html{
    root $document_root/error_pages; //FAILS HERE with the error in the title
    internal;
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This variable is set by `root` directive. You cannot use it in `root` directive itself, because it will lead to infinite loop.

See http://nginx.org/r/root

> The *path* value can contain variables, except `$document_root` and `$realpath_root`.

Use your own variable instead.

```
set $my_root folder/my_root;
root /$my_root;
...

location = /404.html {
    root /$my_root/error_pages;
}
```

And don't try to put leading slash into variable. `root $var` will look for `$var` in some default directory like `/usr/local/nginx` or `/etc/nginx`.